# 'Unable to untar' using Drush 7 on Windows 8.1 - How to resolve?

Tags: windows, drupal, windows-8.1, tar, drush

I'm trying to get drush running on  my windows machine. I mainly followed this guide [here](http://drupalistasgroup.com/installing-drush-7-windows-xampp).

I am using Windows 8.1, 64 bit, and Drush v 7.0 dev

When I type `drush status` I get the right results. But when I try to use `drush dl drupal` I get these error messages:

```
Unable to untar C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\drush_tmp_1413483869_54400d5d5328e\dru564.tmp.              [error]

Unable to create                                                                                               [error]

C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp/drush_tmp_1413483869_54400d5d5328e/drupal-7.32/drupal-7.32/drupal-7.32/drupal-7.32/
drupal-7.32/drupal-7.32/drupal-7.32/drupal-7.32/drupal-7.32/drupal-7.32/drupal-7.32/drupal-7.32/drupal-7.32/drupal-7.32/
drupal-7.32.
Unable to copy C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp/drush_tmp_1413483869_54400d5d5328e/ to                       [error]

C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp/drush_tmp_1413483869_54400d5d5328e/drupal-7.32.
Unable to move C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp/drush_tmp_1413483869_54400d5d5328e/ to                       [error]

C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp/drush_tmp_1413483869_54400d5d5328e/drupal-7.32.
```

I have installed gzip like it's described in the guide and I have renamed  C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\bsdtar.exe to C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\tar.exe.

Is there really no easy way to install Drush on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Your Drush is setup and works fine, but you miss some Unix libraries. Probably 
`ncurses`, `bsdtar`, `bzr`.

I don't use the GnuWin32, instead I use Cygwin and PATH the cygwin/bin.

Comment: Thanks! This answer helped me get drush working on Cygwin. I used `apt-cyg install ncurses bsdtar bzr`.